# Gathering multiple mapper's result sorted at Reducer in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning, bigdata

I have multiple very large files(nearly 500MB) as input to my MR program. I divide(split) these files into equal size partitions. Each Mapper gets
single partition of a file

Mapper : Key=(filename, partition_number) and Value= (character stream of partition)

I am applying some computation on value(character stream) in mapper.
I want to gather result corresponding to a input file(for all of its partitons) in one reducer. So I thought of reducer i/p key as 'filename'. But those output from mapper must be gathered sequentially in reducer.( like [partition1 o/p + partition2  +...+partitionN o/p] )

Can you plz suggest me the logic.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a secondary sort. For an example see https://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/secondary-sorting-aka-sorting-values-in-hadoops-mapreduce-programming-paradigm/

In this case"

- Primary Comparator compares on [filename, partition_number]
- Group Comparator on filename only
- Partitioner on filename only